# Will Ubuntu support my Lenovo Laptop?

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

I want to move from WINDOWS to Ubuntu Desktop OS, is my machine matches the requirements to install Ubuntu. Below is my specs of machine.

```
Version: 10.0.19045 Build 19045
System Manufacturer LENOVO
System Model:   20VE
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU: LENOVO_MT_20VE_BU_idea_FM_ThinkBook 15 G2 ITL
Processor:  11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 2803 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date:  LENOVO F8CN45WW(V2.08), 11/2/2021
```

Please guide.

Comment: Why not *Try Ubuntu before install* ?  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install   This will work for most Ubuntu *flavors* too, you didn't specify what Ubuntu product; ie. Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Core? etc.

Comment: I have edit my question. I want to install Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: The Lenovo ThinkBook 15 G2 ITL has an Intel Core i7 11th Gen processor and 8GB RAM. It supports all flavors of Ubuntu.

Comment: I think the answer below is probably wrong - I’d hazard a guess that your laptop will work fine. Download the Ubuntu (probably 22.04LTS) desktop iso, select ‘try Ubuntu’ and you’ll get a pretty good idea where it’ll work or not. Nothing to lose by doing that.

Answer (score -2):

I think the latest lenovo 15 is not supportive with the latest version of ubuntu 22.04. You have to wait for their new release 23.10 which was expected in July, 2024. Try Ubuntu before Ubuntu Install will guide/tell you the end result(supportive or not).

Comment: Can you cite any source to support your claim that Ubuntu 22.04 is not compatible with this laptop?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS was four releases ago (back in 2022-April which is why it was 22.04; it was followed by Ubuntu 22.10 in 2022-October, Ubuntu 23.04 in 2023-April & Ubuntu 23.10 in 2023-October).  Ubuntu 23.10 is the *latest* release of Ubuntu being from 2023-October; ie. late last year.

Comment: after successfull installation, it throws some error while booting. The system work normally, but it will stuck/hang sometime.

Comment: Is your difficulty with this particular laptop and 22.04? I’m very surprised it won’t install and work.